# How do you split a list of typles into two separate lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list

i have a list of tuples that i am trying to convert to two different lists called 'list x' and 'list y'. Here is the list.

```
[('[(0.07, 6380.0), (0.14, 6653.0), (0.3, 6672.0), (0.45, 6699.0), (0.56, 6738.0), (1.01, 6783.0), (1.47, 6827.0), (1.93, 6867.0), (2.39, 6912.0), (3.08, 6942.0), (3.85, 6976.0), (4.61, 6975.0), (5.38, 6972.0), (6.33, 7012.0), (7.38, 7018.0), (8.43, 6990.0), (9.49, 7018.0), (10.67, 7050.0), (11.97, 7060.0), (13.27, 7027.0), (14.57, 7056.0), (15.96, 7104.0), (17.44, 7096.0), (18.93, 7120.0), (20.42, 
7156.0), (21.96, 7180.0), (23.57, 7205.0), (25.19, 7214.0), (26.81, 7303.0), (28.43, 7336.0), (30.11, 7311.0), (31.79, 7278.0), (33.46, 7284.0), (35.14, 7256.0), (36.82, 7194.0), (38.49, 7185.0), (40.16, 7279.0), (41.84, 7325.0), (43.48, 7361.0), (45.11, 7423.0), (46.75, 7532.0), (48.38, 7555.0), (49.94, 7530.0), (51.5, 7509.0), (53.06, 7500.0), (54.63, 7447.0), (56.09, 7420.0), (57.55, 7434.0), (59.02, 7503.0), (60.48, 7635.0), (61.87, 7764.0), (63.22, 7870.0), (64.57, 7916.0), (65.93, 7933.0), (67.22, 7878.0), (68.47, 7754.0), (69.71, 7646.0), (70.96, 7572.0), (72.16, 7531.0), (73.31, 7525.0), 
(74.44, 7602.0), (75.58, 7700.0), (76.69, 7771.0), (77.73, 7840.0), (78.76, 7907.0), (79.8, 7869.0), (80.82, 7776.0), (81.76, 7687.0), (82.69, 7583.0), (83.63, 7489.0), (84.56, 7481.0), (85.4, 7573.0), (86.24, 7709.0), (87.08, 7837.0), (87.91, 7967.0), (88.67, 8059.0), (89.41, 8059.0), (90.15, 7972.0), (90.89, 7837.0), (91.57, 7708.0), (92.21, 7615.0), (92.86, 7599.0), (93.5, 7660.0), (94.1, 7819.0), (94.65, 8009.0), (95.19, 8212.0), (95.74, 8351.0), (96.25, 8390.0), (96.69, 8322.0), (97.13, 8154.0), (97.57, 7961.0), (97.99, 7767.0), (98.33, 7648.0), (98.66, 7674.0), (98.99, 7878.0), (99.31, 8162.0), (99.52, 8426.0), (99.72, 8638.0), (99.93, 8740.0), (100.13, 8566.0), (100.21, 8263.0), (100.28, 7938.0), (100.34, 7636.0), (100.45, 7329.0), (100.35, 6998.0), (100.25, 6652.0), (100.16, 6285.0), (100.06, 6010.0), (99.85, 5813.0), (99.57, 5623.0), (99.29, 5456.0), (99.01, 5167.0), (98.63, 4852.0), (98.15, 4779.0), (97.68, 4722.0), (97.2, 4678.0), (96.64, 4612.0), (95.95, 4572.0), (95.27, 4614.0), (94.58, 4629.0), (93.85, 4643.0), (92.95, 4648.0), (92.06, 4599.0), (91.17, 4504.0), (90.26, 4424.0), (89.18, 4374.0), (88.09, 4303.0), (87.01, 4266.0), (85.93, 4300.0), (84.69, 4358.0), (83.44, 4392.0), (82.19, 4405.0), (80.94, 4429.0), (79.58, 4388.0), (78.19, 4274.0), (76.82, 4167.0), (75.44, 4073.0), (73.98, 3973.0), (72.5, 3915.0), (71.01, 3932.0), (69.54, 3998.0), (68.01, 4083.0), (66.47, 4192.0), (64.92, 4269.0), (63.36, 4242.0), (61.79, 4176.0), (60.2, 4055.0), (58.61, 3881.0), (57.02, 3711.0), (55.43, 3599.0), (53.83, 3571.0), (52.23, 3599.0), (50.63, 3739.0), (49.03, 3972.0), (47.44, 
4185.0), (45.84, 4272.0), (44.25, 4261.0), (42.65, 4187.0), (41.09, 4000.0), (39.53, 3767.0), (37.97, 3589.0), (36.41, 3530.0), (34.91, 3528.0), (33.41, 3646.0), (31.91, 3851.0), (30.41, 4073.0), (28.94, 4220.0), (27.52, 4295.0), (26.09, 4283.0), (24.66, 4053.0), (23.27, 3755.0), (21.95, 3512.0), (20.63, 3368.0), (19.32, 3288.0), (18.01, 3477.0), (16.81, 3780.0), (15.62, 4069.0), (14.42, 4338.0), (13.2, 4566.0), (12.15, 4643.0), (11.1, 4273.0), (10.06, 3955.0), (9.01, 3639.0), (8.09, 3341.0), (7.23, 3059.0), (6.37, 3156.0), (5.51, 3557.0), (4.73, 3935.0), (4.09, 4301.0), (3.43, 4673.0), (2.78, 5027.0), (2.19, 5338.0), (1.78, 5525.0), (1.36, 5754.0), (0.95, 5908.0), (0.57, 6007.0), (0.43, 6117.0), (0.28, 6227.0), (0.14, 6349.0), (0.07, 6380.0)]', )]
```

I am trying to use the split and reshape option but its throwing an error.

```
surface_data_card_list = surface_data_card.split(',')
surface_data_card_list = [float(i) for i in surface_data_card_list]
surface_data_card_list = np.reshape(surface_data_card_list,(-1,2))
print(surface_data_card_list)
```

the error message is

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(0.07'
```

is there a simpler way of doing this? The results that i am looking for would look something like this so i can plot it.

```
list of x values            list of y values
(0.07, 0.14, 0.3, ...), (6380.0, 6653.0, 6672.0, ...)
```

Comment: you want two lists, one with the first index of each tuple and one with the second?

Comment: From the error, you don't have a list of tuples, you have a string that *looks* like a list of tuples.

Comment: i updated the question to show the desired outcome. So that makes sense that its  a string that looks like tuples since i query it from an SQL table column with NVARCHAR(MAX) as its datatype. So i guess there are two problems then. 1) i need the string to be converted to tuples 2) separate the tuples into a x list and a y list for plotting (i provided an example of the desired data output in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your given data, you have a list of tuples of strings of lists of tuples (if I'm counting correctly). What you need to do first is to remove both the outmost list and tuple to get to the strings.

```
mystring = lst[0][0]
```

Next, you can use `eval` to turn the strings into list of tuples.

```
newlist = eval(mystring)
```

Finally, you can use `zip` to get your desired output.

```
a, b = zip(*newlist)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
lst_x, lst_y = list(zip(*lst))
```

Comment: That creates two tuples (which is probably okay), but if the OP really wants lists he should do `lst_x, lst_y = map(list, zip(*lst))`.